# Why does an f minor scale sound good on a c major chord?

Tags: scales, chord-progressions

I've been looping a C major chord on an app, and tried to play the F minor scale on that. Why does this work? I know that A minor is the relative scale of C major and that should sound good. But why does F minor sound so good on a C major chord?

Comment: You are essentially playing C Phrygian (a minor mode equivalent to the F natural minor scale) over **C**; you are getting the exotic sound of the Phrygian scale superimposed on the **C** chord.

Comment: Or, if you like, C Phrygian contains the same notes as Ab major. Except we don't actually know *which* minor scale notes you're using...

Comment: Which minor scale? F melodic minor fits a lot more nicely while still retaining that minor plagal feel. F dorian is much smoother than F natural minor, sinc the D♭ is going to clash with the C of the chord... F pentatonic minor could also be nice, leaving a little more room for the chord... I feel like these minor scales would be better in the *key* of C major, not over the *chord* C major*.

Comment: I think all the answers and comments are provisional until you explain how you are handling scale degrees 6 and especially 7. In other words, are you using 'natural' minor or any scale form with the raised seventh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that by "F minor scale" you mean the F natural minor scale, not F melodic minor, F harmonic minor, or some other minor mode.

The notes of the F natual minor scale are also the notes of the C Phrygian scale: C Db Eb F G Ab Bb. Now a **C** triad contains the notes C-E-G; the only problem is that **C** has an E natural in it, but C Phrygian has an Eb which would seem to clash with the third of the **C**.

### A Diversion Into the Diminished Whole Tone Scale

This reminds me of what is called the *altered scale*, also known as the *diminished whole tone scale*. The altered scale is the scale derived from the seventh mode of the melodic minor scale, so the C altered scale would be: C Db Eb Fb Gb Ab Bb. Here is some tablature to compare the two:

C Phrygian

```
$A 3 4 6 $D 3 5 6 $G 3 5
```

C altered (C diminished whole tone)

```
$A 3 4 6 $D 2 4 6 $G 3 5
```

This C altered scale is usually paired with what is called a **C7alt** chord. But, in this application, the C altered scale isn't spelled the way I have spelled it above, but rather using an enharmonically equivalent spelling: C Db D# E F# G# Bb (giving a **C7(#5b9#9#11)** chord) or C Db D# E Gb Ab Bb (giving a **C7(b5b9#9b13)** chord). That is, you can construct a **C7** chord with the 5th and all of the extensions altered any way you like, so long as they are altered.

You can play a C altered scale over a **C7** chord (or even over a **C** chord in some circumstances). These altered scales are usually played over an altered dominant seventh chord, i.e. **C7b9**, **C7#9**, **C7#9#11**, and so on. Often in a jazz chart you will find a **C7alt** chord which means that the exact alterations to the seventh chord are left up to the player, but an altered scale is appropriate here. Generally speaking, altered scales are a little bit tricky to use.

### Returning to the Phrygian Scale: Poor Man's Altered Scale?

The C Phrygian scale was: C Db Eb F G Ab Bb, but instead we could spell it as C Db D# F G Ab Bb. This gives a **C7(b9#9b13)** chord, except that the third (E) is missing. But since the scale is played over a **C** chord, that E is present in the harmony. In this sense the C Phrygian scale is something of a poor man's C altered scale.

In this interpretation, the C Phrygian scale provides a way to elaborate a **C7** chord. By playing C Phrygian over a **C** chord, you are converting it to a **C7** chord, with some alterations.

Comment: Haha, I was wondering where your comment about the poor man's alt scale went. Couldn't have said it better myself. +1

Comment: @user45266 -- thanks; the comment was under Tim's answer. I made it in a kind of offhand way this morning, and when I came back I thought that maybe I should turn it into an answer ;)

Comment: I must have checked at like the worst time possible to have seen the deleted comment and not the answer. Ah well, I much prefer the answer to its comment form.

Answer (score 5):

A C major chord has a close relationship to the F minor scale.  The dominant of F minor is C.  Also, although E is flat in the key signature of F minor, as the leading note (just before the tonic F), it is often before raised to E natural.  So, a C major chord is common in F minor and will lead to the tonic chord F minor.

Comment: I tried playing an F minor scale over a C major chord.  I did not like the effect but tastes vary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we will have to agree to disagree. I really don't think most of the F minor notes sound good at all against a C major chord. There are 3 notes which fit exactly - C F and G, but the others are a semitone away from any in the C scale, and the E♭ clashes against the major 3 of C. This in itself is no big deal: blues often uses the m3 against the major version of a chord. It also uses B♭, but those apart, nothing else works - in my opinion. And opinions aren't really what the site is about!

Comment: it seems to me that playing C Phrygian over a **C** triad could be a little like playing a poor-man's C Alt scale here. Tricky to handle well, but potentially useful.

Comment: @DavidBowling - yes, C Phrygian is what it amounts to. But playing any parallel mode is pretty tricky, unless you know what you're up to - or rather lucky...

Comment: well, I've never been that lucky, and I only know what I'm up to when I'm not paying attention....

Comment: @DavidBowling - it's a good attitude - don't let thinking get in the way of making good music. I thought once. Never again...